# CHCSVParsing an unusual csv file

Tags: objective-c, parsing, csv

I'm having difficulties as to how I should parse this kind of csv file.

For example:

```
06:16 PM,7,299,http://cdn.worldweatheronline.net/images/wsymbols01_png_64/wsymbol_0026_heavy_rain_showers_night.png,Moderate rain at times,14,22,180,S,3.1,81,10,993,75
2014-01-31,9,48,3,38,22,35,176,S,119,http://cdn.worldweatheronline.net/images/wsymbols01_png_64/wsymbol_0003_white_cloud.png,Cloudy,6.0
2014-02-01,7,45,3,37,19,30,220,SW,113,http://cdn.worldweatheronline.net/images/wsymbols01_png_64/wsymbol_0001_sunny.png,Sunny,2.2
2014-02-02,9,47,3,37,17,27,236,SW,113,http://cdn.worldweatheronline.net/images/wsymbols01_png_64/wsymbol_0001_sunny.png,Sunny,0.0
2014-02-03,8,46,3,37,21,34,152,SSE,116,http://cdn.worldweatheronline.net/images/wsymbols01_png_64/wsymbol_0002_sunny_intervals.png,Partly Cloudy,1.8
2014-02-04,9,48,3,38,20,32,191,SSW,263,http://cdn.worldweatheronline.net/images/wsymbols01_png_64/wsymbol_0009_light_rain_showers.png,Patchy light drizzle,1.4
"London","United Kingdom","City Of London, Greater London",51.517,-0.106,7421228,http://www.worldweatheronline.com/London-weather/City-of-London-Greater-London/GB.aspx
```

For example, I need to get the first two values on the first line, all the values on the 2nd to 6th line, and the first value of the 7th line.

I currently have a model class with properties for all the values I need to get.

I'm not sure how to do it in this situation. So far, I know how to parse that csv (if I didn't need to get the first two values on the 1st line, and the first value of the 7th line)

What would be the logic to parse in this situation? Hope you guys can give me some idea how to do it.

Thanks

Comment: How are you currently parsing?

Comment: I'm using the CHCSVParser that Dave DeLong developed for Objective-C. It has delegate methods which I use to parse

Comment: Why is your CSV file unusual? It's not. Just keep track of the row you are processing and grab just the column data you need for that row.

Comment: Yeah, I didn't know how to describe the situation. My mistake. Thanks for the comment

Answer (score 1):

Split the string into lines (busing a scanner or array method depending on how big the string is). Once you have your lines, takes the special ones and pass to appropriate methods to extract the required values. Likewise for the main lines.

You can use your parser on each line individually or use a scanner or array method if that's easier depending on what content you need to extract and where it is.